# How do I create global variables I can use across my modules?

Tags: javascript

I import scene from file `sceneSetup.js` into `initFloor1.js` and get error ReferenceError: `scene is not defined`
Can't find solution of this issue and can't understand if it is the issue of javascript or Threejs

sceneSetup.js:

```
export let camera, controls, renderer, labelRenderer, renderer3D, arrow, label, scene;
```

initFloor1.js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { camera, controls, renderer, labelRenderer, renderer3D, arrow, label, scene } from './../sceneSetup.js'
            
export function initFloor1() {
                
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

My project folder:

```
|- src
|  |- 3d-scene
|     |- sceneSetup.js
|     |- Floor1  
|        |- initFloor1.js
```

Comment: Not a threeJS issue.

Comment: What is `THREE`?

Comment: JavaScript library. It is imported in "initFloor1.js", as u see

Comment: The exports from `sceneSetup.js` are all undefined. Why do you think the would be defined?

Comment: I have no idea why they all are undefined. Can you explain?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "scene is read-only". Not sure you can just export single variables like that. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let

Comment: Export an object instead: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-allen-on5s2?file=/src/sceneSetup.js

Comment: The variables have no value, that's why they're undefined. Where do you think they should be getting their values from?

Comment: @evolutionxbox This is not about the variables initially being undefined, at all. OP is trying to create global variables, and trying to *assign a value* to `scene`, not read from it. OP does *not* expect scene to have a value despite it clearly having none.

Comment: @ChrisG yup yup, I see that now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060519/es6-import-as-a-read-only-view-understanding might help

Comment: @ChrisG, thank you. Your solution helped me

Answer (score 1):

Solution, suggested by [ChrisG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) : export an object and edit its values

```
const globals = {
      camera: null,
      controls: null,
      renderer: null,
      labelRenderer: null,
      renderer3D: null,
      arrow: null,
      label: null,
      scene: null
    };
    
    export { globals };
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.variableName` to declare in central place and then you can access across the site.

```
window.camera=null;
window.controls=null;
```

etc.

Comment: I assume the OP is trying to avoid this

Comment: Well this is one way OP can use. I shared because this is valid way and I use it across the site..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28433971)

Comment: @Eydrian :Revised for better understanding